# How to add some information into jQuery dataTables column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datatables, cell

I have this code:

```
 $("table.contentTable").dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sUrl": "scripts/language/ru_RU.txt"
        },
        "aaSorting": sorting,
        /* "bJQueryUI": true,*/
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sPaginationType": "paging_with_jqui_icons",
        "sAjaxSource": "getAllTripCards",
        "fnServerData": fnDataTablesPipeline,
        "aoColumns": [
            {"mDataProp": "cardNumber"},
            {"mDataProp": "issueDate", "sType": "string-date-euro"},
            {"mDataProp": "type"},
            {"mDataProp": "position"}
```

...

I need to add a combination of two fields in into a first column. How can I do that? I want to make this, but it doesn't work

```
 "aoColumns": [
            {"mDataProp": "cardNumber" + "issueDate"},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `column().header()` API to get the column header cell.

You can try this :

```
$(table.column(1).header()).text('cardNumber/year');
```

Reference link:

[column().header() API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().header())

Answer (score 0):

you can write it like this:

```
"aoColumns": [
        {"mDataProp": "cardNumber"},
        { "mDataProp": function (data, type, dataToSet) {
        return data.issueDate + " " + data.sType;}},
        {"mDataProp": "type"},
        {"mDataProp": "position"}
```

],